# How much time does it take to get a release letter from a university?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I got in to university A for the Fall, but now I want to go to university B. April 15 has passed which means I need a release letter from university A. University B will accept me if I get this release letter.

In your experience, how much time could it take to get this release letter? I need to know this because university B has given me a deadline.

Comment: I don't think anybody here in this site would know the exact time. But, my best guess would be a week at least.

Answer (score 1):

I think it`s better to ask them about the time! Or even ask responsible department/ person about this letter. If he does not answer in 2-3 days, send him something like:

"Dear Professor ... , Sorry for bothering you, I just want to check if you had a chance to read my e-mail about ...? I would appreciate if you reply

Best regards, ... "

It really helps!!